Trial exclusion in eye-tracking data?
In an eye-tracking dataset, is it reasonable to exclude all trials with a blink or saccade in the 150 ms before stimulus onset? As an alternative, would it be better to exclude blinks (after extending them by about 100 ms before and after the start of a trial) and then exclude all trials where missing data exceeds a certain threshold, say 20%?
